# Find A(1, 1, 2) given eigenvalues 2 and 5 and eigenvectors (1, 1, -1), (1, -1, 0) that span the 5-eigenspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[This is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7C3MS.png)

How can I do this? I know it's basic understanding, but this is my first exposure to this material. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: The cross product $$(1,1,-1)\times (1,-1,0)$$ is in the eigenspace of $\lambda=2$. Do you know why?

Comment: No, I'm not really sure why is this the case.

Comment: Eigenvectors for distinct eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix are orthogonal.

Comment: I see. But how would this help me compute A(1, 1, 2)? I'm sorry if I don't get it yet.

Comment: Once you find the cross product mentioned in my first comment you have a set of three linearly independent eigenvectors that span all of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Now express $(1,1,2)$ as a linear combination of these eigenvectors.

Comment: This is obviously an exercise. Please share first what you have tried to do.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I found the orthogonal vector to the given eigenvectors (precisely (1, 1, 2)), which we know has eigenvalue 2 (since the other two eigenvectors have eigenvalue 5). Then A(1, 1, 2) = 2(1, 1, 2) = (2, 2, 4). Is this correct?